# Get jQuery function to trigger on HTML Button OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, button

I have the following HTML/JQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Login</title>
<script src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){                     
      $(function(){
         $("#sb").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            getmessage = "Yes";
            getmessage = encodeURIComponent(getmessage);//url encodes data
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "get_login.php",
               data: {'getmessage': getmessage},
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(data) {
                  $("#message_ajax").html("<div class='successMessage'>" + data.message +"</div>");
           }
           });
        });
      });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<p>Please enter your e-mail and password</p>
<form name = "loginform" action = "http://dev.speechlink.co.uk/David/get_login.php" method = "post">
<p>E-mail<input name = "username" type="text" size="25"/><label id ="emailStatus"></label></p>

<p>Password<input name = "password" type="text" size="25"/><label id ="passwordStatus"></label></p>

<p><input type="hidden" name="usertype" value = "SupportStaff" /></p>
<p>><input type ="button" id = "sb"value="Create Account"/></p>

</form>
<div id = "message_ajax"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot get the event handler (within the jQuery) to trigger upon the user pressing the 'Create Account' button...

Comment: You really ought to remove all those irregular spaces from attributes. Also `$(function() {` inside a `.ready` is superfluous as it does the same thing.

Comment: Knowing what actually happens when you click the button would be useful; there's a quite substantial difference between nothing visibly happening and nothing actually happening. Do you get any browser errors? Do you get a response from the AJAX call? Does the event actually fire?

Comment: The HTML for your button seems to have extra spaces at somes place, and missing space between "sb" value="Create Account". That might be it. Also, why are you embeding $(function(){ into $(document).ready... your code already gets called only on DOM ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You html is not good:

> `<p>><input type ="button" id = "sb" value="Create Account"/></p>`

should be

> `<p><input type ="button" id="sb" value="Create Account"/></p>`

Answer (score 3):

I see three issues off-the-bat:

1. You're calling `ready` twice (when you pass a function into `$()`, it's just like passing a function into `$(document).ready()`). This is largely harmless, but completely unnecessary.
2. Your attribute for the `id` on the button is rammed up against the next; it's possible the browser is ignoring it:

   ```
   <input type ="button" id = "sb"value="Create Account"/>
   <!--                  ^^^^^^^^^ -->
   ```

   (It's fine to have spaces around the `=` if you want, but having the `"sb"` rammed up into `value` may not work.)
3. (Possibly off-topic, possibly not): You seem (from the quoted code) to be falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You should probably declare your `getmessage` variable.

So:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){           
     // Removed the unnecessary `$(function() { ...` here and the matching closing bits at the end
     $("#sb").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var getmessage = "Yes"; // <== Added `var`
        getmessage = encodeURIComponent(getmessage);//url encodes data
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "get_login.php",
           data: {'getmessage': getmessage},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data) {
              $("#message_ajax").html("<div class='successMessage'>" + data.message +"</div>");
       }
       });
    });
    });
</script>
```

and

```
<input type="button" id="sb" value="Create Account"/>
```

Comment: I tested having the id and value attributes without a space in IE9, FF5 and Chrome 12 and it worked fine in all three. It's possible it's not working with earlier versions of these browsers, but I imagine it's not the only issue with what he's written.

Comment: @Anthony: I imagine not. I seem to recall it working as well when I saw it in some code a couple of years back.